# .html() function of jQuery only working on the first element

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a system for an assignment given to us with my partner using wordpress and php. We've done some work already but there's this one problem I'm  having trouble with.

Whenever I use the .html() function in ajax only the first element of the tab gets the query result I have

Here are my codes:

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <body>
                                <!--- START HEADER -->
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                    <h1 id="logo">Logo</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="myBtn">Create Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Metrics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
                                <!--- END HEADER -->

                                <!--- START MAIN CONTENT -->

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="teamholder">
                <!--- ACCORDION HTML -->
                <!--- END OF ACCORDION HTML -->
            </div>

            <div id="profileholder">
            </div>

            <div id="randomdiv">
            </div>
        </div>
```

teams.php

```
<?php
    // Display members from database
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'chansandbox');

    if(isset($_POST['display'])){
        $team = "SELECT * FROM team";
        $resultTeam = mysqli_query($connect, $team);

        while($arrayTeam = mysqli_fetch_array($resultTeam)){
            ?>
                <ul class="teams">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><?php echo $arrayTeam['team_name']; ?></a>
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li id="memberholder">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?php
        }
        exit();
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
```

members.php

```
<?php
// Display members from database
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'chansandbox');

    if(isset($_POST['display'])){
        /*
        $numTeams = "SELECT count(*) AS 'number' FROM team";
        $resultNumTeams = mysqli_query($connect, $numTeams);
        $arrayNumTeams = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNumTeams);

        for($i=$arrayNumTeams['number'];)
        */

        $member = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        $resultMember = mysqli_query($connect, $member);

        while($arrayMember = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMember)){
            ?>
                <h1><?php echo $arrayMember['emp_fname'] . " " . $arrayMember['emp_lname']; ?></h1>
            <?php
        }
        exit();
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
```

script.js

```
//------------- ACCORDION DISPLAY DATA ------------//

function displayTeamFromDatabase($){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:81/chansandbox/wp-content/themes/Skeleton/teams.php",
        method: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {
            "display": 1
        },
        success: function(d){
            $("#teamholder").html(d);
        }
    });
}

function displayMemberFromDatabase($){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:81/chansandbox/wp-content/themes/Skeleton/members.php",
        method: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {
            "display": 1
        },
        success: function(d){
            $("#memberholder").html(d);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to show all the data of the employee table to each tab of the responsive accordion to which it generates a new tab for each entry inside the team table. What I don't understand is why only the first tab has the list of data from the employee table.

Any reply would be appreciated, thank you.

Also I used this guide as reference for the teams and members.php
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTQU_veJ6Kk&feature=youtu.be&t=1391

Comment: What is a “tab”? If it’s `<div class="wrapper">`, then it means you’re using the ID `teamholder` (and others) twice. IDs must be unique in a document. Use classes instead.

Comment: Also, I noticed, you copied the `async: false` from the tutorial, which is both pointless in this case, and bad practice. I really wouldn’t recommend this tutorial.

Comment: My bad, what I mean by tab is the tab for the accordion that when you click it it'll drop down with the list of employees which in this case is the <ul class = "teams"> in the teams.php file. If I remove the async: false in the script the accordion wont drop down at all I don't know what is causing this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead $("#teamholder").html(d); use:

```
$("[id=teamholder]").each(function(){
   $(this).html(d);
});
```

and instead $("#memberholder").html(d); :

```
$("[id=memberholder]").each(function(){
   $(this).html(d);
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `.each()` loop if you are setting them all to have the same value, you can just say `$("[id=teamholder]").html(d)`, but in any case this is still not ideal because duplicate IDs is invalid HTML - much better to switch to using a common class.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes I agree it's not optimized but we also need to think about person's level, who will use it. Better to show not optimized but easy to understand and implement in provided code.